# I want to change the rows into columns but only for office1 is displayed and i want for both offices

Tags: mysql

I have a table in the database showing how the organization spends

```
Office   Year  Quarter  Computer  Keyboard  Monitor  Total
Office1  2014  Q1       1000      300       400      1700
Office1  2014  Q2        400      100         0       500
Office1  2014  Q3        500        0       300       800
Office2  2014  Q1       1500      250       250      2000
Office2  2014  Q2        400      250       250       900
Office2  2014  Q3       1000      100       100      1200
```

I want the table to be like

```
office   Year  Usage     Q1    Q2   Q3
Office1  2014  Computer  1000  400   500
Office1  2014  Keyboard   300  100     0
Office1  2014  Monitor    400    0   300
Office1  2014  Total     1700  500   800
Office2  2014  Computer  1500  400  1000
Office2  2014  Keyboard   250  250   100
Office2  2014  Monitor    250  250   100
Office2  2014  Total     2000  900  1200
```

I have tried the following code but displays only usage for office 1

```
SELECT usage,
       MAX(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q1' THEN value END) Q1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q2' THEN value END) Q2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q3' THEN value END) Q3
  FROM
(
  SELECT quarter, usage,
         CASE usage 
            WHEN 'computer' THEN COMPUTER
            WHEN 'keyboard' THEN KEYBOARD
            WHEN 'monitor' THEN MONITOR
            WHEN 'total' THEN TOTAL

         END value
    FROM OfficeUsageTable t CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'Computer' usage UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Keyboard' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Monitor' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Total'
  ) c
) q
 GROUP BY usage;
```

The table displayed is only for office1 ie

```
office   Year  Usage     Q1    Q2   Q3
Office1  2014  Computer  1000  400  500
Office1  2014  Keyboard   300  100    0
Office1  2014  Monitor    400    0  300
Office1  2014  Total     1700  500  800
```

And I would like all data for the two offices to be displayed.
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

`USAGE` is a [*MySQL reserved word*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). Hence it is advised not to use as column/alias name in (sub)queries. Instead `'usg'` is used in the subquery, in this answer.

You need few changes in your query as follows:

**Change 1**: You need to include `office`, and `year` from main table `OfficeUsageTable`.

**Change 2**: You need to group by both `office` and `usg` fields.

Try the following:

```
SELECT office as 'Office', year as 'Year', usg as 'Usage',
  MAX(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q1' THEN value END) Q1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q2' THEN value END) Q2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN quarter = 'q3' THEN value END) Q3
FROM
(
  SELECT office, year, quarter, usg,
    CASE usg 
      WHEN 'computer' THEN COMPUTER
      WHEN 'keyboard' THEN KEYBOARD
      WHEN 'monitor' THEN MONITOR
      WHEN 'total' THEN TOTAL
    END value
  FROM OfficeUsageTable t CROSS JOIN
  (
    SELECT 'Computer' as usg UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Keyboard' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Monitor' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Total'
  ) c
) q
GROUP BY office, usg
```